# What do the letters mean as Win32api arguments?

Tags: ruby, winapi

I'm using the `Win32api` module. I want to know what the `L's` and `P's` mean in the following line:

```
function = Win32API.new('user32', 'MessageBox', ['L', 'P', 'P', 'L'], 'I')
```

I know that `user32` is the dll from which the `MessageBox` function is called from, but what do the `L's`, `P's`, and the `I` do, more specifically what do they stand for?

Comment: So your code means that call `MessageBox` method which has argment type of `(Long,Pointer,Pointer,Long)` and returns `Integer`.  You can confirm that this matches https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox

Comment: http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/lib_windows.html#Win32API

Comment: On another note, `Win32API` is quite deprecated, and you should be using `Fiddle` if your Ruby version > 2.0, as Win32API is simply translated into it anyways.